# gzip files with cat and from pipe gives different results

Tags: bash, diff, gzip

Why does this give such output (both commands are supposed to do the same thing) and how can one make them give identical output?

```
diff <(cat some_file | gzip -c - | base64) <(gzip -c some_file | base64)
1,2c1,2
< H4sIACSOZFUAA2XNsRHAMAgDwDqZRkIQ8P6L+c5xnIL2m2c5E6BdIQA5cHPTaGTqlI3ki2jSoWrk
< e1Tw0PNSMT4KdPKfJgNiJT++AAAA
---
> H4sICGcqSlUAA2Z0X2FkLnNob3J0AGXNsRHAMAgDwDqZRkIQ8P6L+c5xnIL2m2c5E6BdIQA5cHPT
> aGTqlI3ki2jSoWrke1Tw0PNSMT4KdPKfJgNiJT++AAAA
```

The contents of the file are:

```
184170012   53000790
184170019   53000790
184170023   53000790
184170027   53000790
184170034   53001233
184170038   53001233
184170042   53000351
184170046   53000815
184170050   53000815
184170054   53000815
```

There is a `tab` character between two columns and `new line` at the end of each line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gzip is encoding the filename of the input file into its output. Even with `-c` option it does this. You can see this with `gzip -c some_file | strings|head -1`. however, when reading from `stdin`, gzip does not do that, since it doesn't know the filename. You can tell gzip to omit from output the filename and time-stamp with `-n`.

Comment: closer but not quite there yet ) `diff <(cat ft_ad.short | gzip -c - | base64) <(gzip -c -n ft_ad.short | base64)
1c1
< H4sIANiRZFUAA2XNsRHAMAgDwDqZRkIQ8P6L+c5xnIL2m2c5E6BdIQA5cHPTaGTqlI3ki2jSoWrk
---
> H4sIAAAAAAAAA2XNsRHAMAgDwDqZRkIQ8P6L+c5xnIL2m2c5E6BdIQA5cHPTaGTqlI3ki2jSoWrk`

Comment: The gz also contains the modification time of the original file, if known, zero bytes if not. This is not prevented when using `-n`. See [RFC 1952](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1952) for details on the file format.

Comment: To get two identical outputs, you need to use `-n` with both `gzip` commands.

Comment: @Dubu `-n` tells `gzip` not to save the file name and time stamp (see http://linux.die.net/man/1/gzip for details).

Comment: @Dubu, putting `-n` in both commands works, thanks